# Can I check the local vairable by using method in other class?

Tags: java

```
public class BookstoreRun {
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BookstoreMenu bm = new BookstoreMenu();
        bm.mainMenu();
    }

}
```

Here's the menu class:

```
public class BookstoreMenu {
    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private BookstoreController bc = new BookstoreController();
    
    public void mainMenu() {
        System.out.println("1. SignUp");
        System.out.println("2. Check members list");
        System.out.println("Select menu : ");
        int menu = sc.nextInt();
        switch (menu) {
        case 1: {
            bc.createAccount();
            break;
        } case 2:
        default:
            System.out.println("...");
        }
    }
}
```

This is controller class where I made methods:

```
public class BookstoreController {
    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void createAccount() {
        System.out.println("Let's get started");
        System.out.print("Your name : ");
        String[] strArray = new String[0];
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        strArray = saveId(strArray, name);
        
        System.out.print(name + ", Nice to meet you!");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
    }
    
    public String[] saveId(String[] originArr, String name) {
        String[] newArr = new String[originArr.length + 1];
        
        System.arraycopy(originArr, 0, newArr, 0, originArr.length);

        newArr[originArr.length] = name;
        return newArr;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a menu with just two options. The first option is Sign Up through `createAccount();` and once I finish signing up, I want to go back to the menu class and choose option 2.

I was thinking I could approach the information of `strArray` in `BookstoreController` class by typing `bc.~` under `case 2` of the switch in the `BookstoreMenu` class, but I failed.

My question is: Is it possible to approach the value which was made in the local area of another class?

Comment: maybe you should show us what you have in your main method then we can know how you are piecing those 2 classes together

Comment: i'm sorry i just edited

Comment: firstly, you can tackle the issue of doing command 1 first then do command 2. right now your logic is such that once user choose menu item 1 and finish the task, the program ends ya? You don't see the menu again correct? Let's fix that first. typically, you can use a while loop to cycle through until a predefined key like 'q' is pressed to exit the loop, thereby exiting the program.

Comment: Local variables cease to exist when a method returns. Did you notice how your `createAccount()` always starts its operation with a zero length array, because there is no array from a previous invocation? You have to store the data in a field of the object (`sc` is a field, for example). By the way, you should not create multiple `Scanner` objects for the same input source. Each `Scanner` has its own buffer, which will lead to problems when you try to read data from one `Scanner` already buffered by the other `Scanner`. Create one `Scanner` and pass it around.

Comment: Now I feel like i should try to make objects with object array. Thanks for your explanation but too hard for me yet grr

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Welcome to the world of Object Oriented Programming OOP & design. One of the more important ideas of OOP is that you encapsulate data and then access it through method calls (or, for other languages, properties).

In this case you should return an `Account` class from `createAccount()`. Then you can have a method there to the `strArray`. That variable should be a *field* in the `Account` class and be renamed to something that reflects its purpose, rather than the types it is made up of (string and arrays).

Now, in modern Java, we store objects like accounts in lists, not arrays. Lists can be grown at your leisure. I've put the list into a field of the controller, so it can be maintained in the right controlled location.

Here is some example:

```
public class BookstoreRun {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BookstoreMenu bm = new BookstoreMenu();
        bm.mainMenu(new Scanner(System.in), System.out);
    }

}

public class BookstoreMenu {
    private BookstoreController bc = new BookstoreController();

    public void mainMenu(Scanner sc, PrintStream out) {

        while (true) {
            // this is a "try with resources", using a localized scanner
            int menu;
            out.println("1. SignUp");
            out.println("2. Check members list");
            out.println("9. Quit");
            out.println("Select menu : ");
            menu = sc.nextInt();

            // either menu has been assigned, or an exception has been thrown, so we can now use it
            switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                bc.createAccount(sc, out);
                break;
            case 2: 
                bc.displayAccounts(out);
                break;
            // always leave yourself an exit option
            case 9:
                out.println("Bye");
                System.exit(0);
            // the default should display an error or warning
            default:
                out.println("Unknown option, try again");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class BookstoreController {

    // the list of accounts that is initially empty, but may grow
    private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    public void createAccount(Scanner sc, PrintStream out) {
        out.println("Let's get started");
        out.println("Your name : ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();

        out.println(name + ", nice to meet you!");
        Account account = new Account(name);
        accounts.add(account);
    }

    public void displayAccounts(PrintStream out) {
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            out.println(account);
        }
    }
}

// this is the additional "data class"
public class Account {
    private String name;

    // constructor that assigns the name to the field
    public Account(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    // a method to retrieve the property name
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }
    
    // this is what is called when it is printed using println (converted to string)
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Account %s", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So you mean I need to make Account class first and make object array so i can make members list with information based on field value in Account class right.. i'm still confused haha

Comment: Added some code for you to grasp it. Note that Account is a so called *data class*, modern Java can use *records* for that.

Comment: I've **refactored** the code, you will probably want to have the accounts in the controller class. So I put the list as a field in the controler.

Comment: Note that you can also put the `while` loop in `BookStoreRun`, probably even better. Makes more sense to me anyway.

Comment: I do appreciate for what you wrote for me it is literally amazing for me! I haven't studied try-resource stuff and don't know much about APIs like List(I'm not sure if that's API or not). Anyway, I have another question; I copied your codes on my eclipse IDE to see the workflow, seperate all the classes in different file and import java util. I have a syntax error on 'private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList()<Account>();' and 'public class Account{~' saying i need to rename. Please give me some more help..

Comment: oh @MaartenBodewes never mind i just solved the problem by pasting your code again! I'll see and study your code right now at 2am you got me excited thank you so much!

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Hi hi I just run the code and i saw the error 'NoSuchElementException' as soon as i press 1. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: As said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447919/can-i-check-the-local-vairable-by-using-method-in-other-class#comment131423845_74447919) you shouldn’t use two different `Scanner` objects for the same input. Using `try(…) { … }` makes it even worse, because it will close the `Scanner` at the end, including its source, which will render the other `Scanner` useless as it uses the same, now closed source.

Comment: Oh yeah, my mistake. I refactored it and then forgot about that part. The idea to have a scanner in different fields is not great either, but I thought it was a bit much to pass the scanner around. Will do that though.